# Api call does not return all objects within array

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am calling this API https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1 and I cannot find all three objects within data property. I can only see first object.

This is the code I am usign

```
        categoryApi.getOne(1).then(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                console.log('categories: ', response.data.data);
            }
        });
```

And this is the response:

```
Object {
 "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg",
   "first_name": "George",
   "id": 1,
   "last_name": "Bluth",
 }
```

and the axios call function looks as below:

```
getOne: id => {
        return axios.get('users?page=1', {
            params: {
                id: id
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                return error;
            } else if (error.request) {
                // The request was made but no response was received
                return error.request;
            } else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                return error.message;
            }
        });
    },
```

Any idea why it only gets first object and not all three objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you also pass `id` in

```
params: {id: id}.
```

Do **not** pass `params`, or pass empty `params`, that's all.